# Direct Injection of NLog into .Net Core project always NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, nlog

I'm new with .Net Core (using 3.1) and using Dependency injection. I was able to setup NLog in the Web API Controller but now I'm trying to get NLog to work in a separate business class following the basics of what I did in the API Controller. I keep get errors about the logger being NULL and when I put a break point on the _logger and _config, sure enough they are NULL. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

This is my Business class and I thought I had it setup correctly but obviously not.

```
public class ShiftBLL
    {
        private static IConfiguration _config;
        private static ILogger<ShiftBLL> _logger;
        
        public ShiftBLL(ILogger<ShiftBLL> logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        

        public static List<AppsShift> GetShifts(string station, string shiftDate)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Staion: {0} | ShiftDate: {1}", station, shiftDate);

             *code removed for clarity. The app breaks on the initial call of _logger.           
        }

    }
```

**FIX**

I removed the "static" from the ShiftBLL class as well as from the local parameters. Then I had to create an object of ShiftBLL in my Controller passing in the logger and config from the controller where I have DI working into the ShiftBLL. I ended up with this in my Controller:

```
ShiftBLL BLL = new ShiftBLL(_logger, _config);

listShifts = BLL.GetShifts(station, shiftDate);
```

Here is my updated ShiftBLL:

```
public class ShiftBLL
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ShiftBLL(ILogger logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        

        public List<AppsShift> GetShifts(string station, string shiftDate)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Staion: {0} | ShiftDate: {1}", station, shiftDate);

        }
```

Still getting my head wrapped around Dependency Injection.

Comment: Could you try removing the "static" keyword from the class fields? They shouldn't be static by design. Edit: I just noticed that even GetShifts is static, is it called from outside the class? Could you share the code of how GetiShifts gets called?

Comment: So I removed static from the class and create an object of ShiftBLL. Looks like that might have worked. I could have sworn I tried that earlier today and it didn't work but looks to know. This is what I created in the Controller...ShiftBLL BLL = new ShiftBLL(_logger, _config);

Comment: Declare like this ‘ private readonly ILogger<ShiftBLL> _logger;’

Comment: Could you please share the program codes or the startup.cs codes about how you register the Nlog ?

Comment: @BrandoZhang This is what I used:  https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

Answer (score 0):

When using DI, the DI container will insert the parameters for all dependencies when needed.

I will try to explain with a simplified example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ShiftBLL shiftBll)
    {  ..  } 
}
```

When resolving MyClass, the DI container will do:

1. Find all needed dependencies for creating an instance of MyClass  - in this case: `ShiftBLL`
2. Find all needed dependencies for creating `ShiftBLL`, in this `ILogger` and `IConfiguration`
3. Find the registrations for `ILogger` and `IConfiguration` (as those are interfaces), and dependencies etc.
4. Create a instance of `ILogger` and `IConfiguration` (via the registrations), create instance of `ShiftBLL` by injecting the instances into the constructor
5. Create a instance of `MyClass` and inject in instance of ShiftBLL.

So with this chain, all your constructor dependencies are created.

But if you're are using static methods in `ShiftBLL`, you are not sure if the constructor of ShiftBLL (with the ILogger) is ever invoked - so the ILogger field could be `null`. .

So to fix this case you could do:

- Make the method non-static, or
- Send all dependencies (ILogger) to the static method as parameter

Answer (score -2):

You mixed up static methods calls and Dependency Injection. I would say to avoid the use of static methods whenever possible, anyway when you are using static methods you cannot access dependencies that are injected through dependency injection. For instance you cannot access _logger from GetShifts because you don't have an instance of ShiftBll and the fact that you call it statically means that its constructor is never called.

This is a working example of how to design classes and their dependencies and how to register them.

```
public class AController : Controller {
    private readonly ILogger<AController> _logger;
    private readonly ShiftBll _shiftBll;

    public AController(ILogger<AController> logger, ShiftBll shiftBll) {
         _logger = logger;
         _shiftBll = shiftBll;
         //I'm pretty sure you didn't inject the dependency here
         //you preferred to use a static reference, but it is not correct in this case
    }
    
    
   public ActionResult AnAction() {
        var shifts = _shiftBll.GetShifts("aStation", "aShiftDate");
   }

}
    public class ShiftBLL
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config; //not static
        private readonly ILogger<ShiftBLL> _logger; //not static
        
        public ShiftBLL(ILogger<ShiftBLL> logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        

        public List<AppsShift> GetShifts(string station, string shiftDate) //not static
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Staion: {0} | ShiftDate: {1}", station, shiftDate);

             *code removed for clarity. The app breaks on the initial call of _logger.           
        }

    }
```

.NET Core DI automatically registers controllers, but you have to manually register your own services. To do this go in the ConfigureServices method of your Startup.cs and add

```
  services.AddScoped<ShiftBll>();
```

now you can use ShiftBll from AController.

Comment: "when you are using static methods you cannot access dependencies that are injected through dependency injection"- this is wrong.  Of *course* you can access static members.  It's just that `_logger` and `_config` will be "null" until the constructor is called :(  But I agree - there's no obvious need for "static" here, and removing "static" should resolve the problem.

Comment: @paulsm4 dependencies can be transient, which means that every instance of the consumer will have a different instance of the dependency. How are you going to make it work with static references? The only way to achieve this is through a static Service Locator, something that .NET Core decided to not include by design. Moreover Service Location is not Dependency Injection. I would be glad to clearify any of your doubts about it.

Comment: Please re-word your response.  It sounds to me like you're implying that "static members" are essentially incompatible with .Net Core's DI.  I can't believe this is true. Please *DON'T* categorically say "avoid the use of static methods whenever possible".  That's just bad advice :(   Focus on the specific problem here (the constructor was never called, hence DI never occurred), which you correctly diagnosed.

Comment: @paulsm4 can you show me a working example of a static method which uses dependencies injected from a DI? Language or framework doesn't matter

Comment: I don't know why you're being marked down for what's basically a "correct" answer.  I don't know why Caverman didn't "accept" it (although I appreciated his updates - that's good practice :)).  And I don't know why you don't update your response to focus more on the immediate question (where "static" wasn't appropriate), perhaps clarifying that "static" is often perfectly appropriate.  Just not here, not now :(  I particularly disagree with the line "avoid the use of static methods whenever possible" :(